# Rails migration t.belongs_to :user, add custom column name seller_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I am trying to add seller_id to my items model in a migration by doing the following:

`rails g model Item title:string description:text price:bigint status:integer published_date:datetime seller:belongs_to`

This didn't work of course...

ultimately I want to see seller_id in my items table, which relates the item model to the user model.

Presently my migration looks like this:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.bigint :price
      t.integer  :status
      t.datetime :published_date
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

1. How can I modify this migration to create a foreign key "seller_id" that relates to the user model.
2. How can I auto generate a migration that includes edits from 1., from the console? I.E modify the rails g model ... to generate the migration I need.

Huge Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explicitly define what you want in the migration file and add the necessary relation to your model, instead of t.belongs_to you could just use:

```
t.integer :seller_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

and in your models you could go about this a few ways, if you also want reference your relation as seller on item instances then in the Item class make the relation:

```
belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
```

and in the User class:

```
has_many :items, foreign_key: :seller_id
```

or if you want to reference it as user from the items then:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :seller_id
```

In terms of editing the generator, that is the default way that a model generator works and in my opinion I like to keep the defaults the way they are. However I do recommend creating your own rails generators or your own rake tasks for when you want to create some custom / special case stuff. For looking at creating your own generator I would point you to the ruby on rails official guide for creating generators to get you started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Answer (score 4):

Inside your migration you can use

```
t.belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
```

Comment: This should be the right Answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want it to be specifically called `seller_id` then what you have is enough. Once you run your migration using `rake db:migrate` you will see the actual table structure in your `db/schema.rb` file with a foreign key `user_id`
2. You can simply edit the generated migration file in your favorite text editor to edit the migration before running `rake db:migrate`

Comment: "Add custom column name seller_id" is specifically in the question. This is a requirement.